# html replace < > to lt gt (text)

Tags: html, textarea

i would replace < to &lt and > to &gt.

I have a text in a textarea. I have a submit button. When i click.

I get the text in the textarea.  I would replace < to &lt and > to &gt.

I need your help.

Not : I don't have a good English.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I can't pardon me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple. Just one google away.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
function myFunction() {
  var textareaElm = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
  var textareaValue = textareaElm.value;
  textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/</g, '&lt');
  textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/>/g, '&gt');
  console.log(textareaValue);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output Result in console.</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.exactly as i want

Comment: Glad that I was able to help. But try googling (rather than asking a question) questions like these .. it would save a lot of your time.